# How do I make an exponential growing chart line on D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I want to make a similar chart like on the picture below, that is drawing a line to a point which increases over time. Numbers on the bottom are seconds (how many passed).

[example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2h4d.gif)
I want to implement this with D3.js, but I do not really understand how to implement it.

I began to look to the side of d3-zoom. But I do not understand how I can make a dynamically growing line. Any similar examples you saw? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think https://bl.ocks.org/pjsier/28d1d410b64dcd74d9dab348514ed256 might be helpful. Just increase the duration of the transition to get the similar effect of your example.

```
function transition(path) {
    path.transition()
        .duration(10000)
        .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash);
}
```